# Speed up Postgres OLTP - eliminate plan time

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, prepared-statement

We have an application with millions of similar queries that are executed in the following way:

```
UPDATE
        flow.thread tr
    SET
        state = $1,
        updated_at = now()
    WHERE
        tr.conversation_number = $2
        AND tr.partner_number = $3
        AND tr.sender_number = $4
        AND tr.channel = $5
        AND tr.status IN ($6,$7,$8)
```

As you may see, this query is parameterized, so does that mean it's already prepared? In `pg_stat_statements` view I can see that this query has 1,065,893 calls and the query has 1,065,893 plans. So looks like we did not get rid of execution plan building or parsing time.

Could you help me figure out this: Doesn't a parameterized query mean that the statement is PREPARED?

Comment: are you connecting through a connection pool?

Comment: yes, developers says the application uses connection pool. 
I monitor sessions on pg_stat_activity - not much new sessions created (about 50 new sessions during 1 million update statemen) so it's highly likely application uses connection pool

Comment: which pooler is used? Don't look surprised to find that when using pgbouncer prepared statements are disabled. If your data has a nice even distribution, you could enable this, or switch to session level pooling instead of transaction level.

Comment: You don't tell us what API and programming language you are using and the code. That makes a difference!

Answer (score 2):

Just because it is parameterized doesn't mean it uses prepared plans.  It is up to the driver to implement that.  For example, some drivers will never use prepared plans and will just interpolate the parameters into the text of the query each time.  Other drivers do other things.